# Blender throws Error: Exception_Access_Violation when Duet Display installed

Tags: opengl

As the title suggests, Blender would throw `Error: Exception_Access_Violation`and not load when I have Duet Display installed. Duet works fine with or without Blender, but Blender will only work when Duet is not installed. I've read about this [problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610918/blender-and-duet-display-issues)
before and understand that it is related to OpenGL. I've already tried to talk to Duet Display, but they weren't helpful (such as asking if Duet Display was working on my iPad).

I would like to be able to use Blender and Duet Display on my PC. Is there a way I can do this?

My Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 370's specs:

1. Intel Core i5-7300
2. 8 GB RAM
3. 64-bit Windows 10
4. Intel HD Graphics 620

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm experiencing this too. Pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Lenovo's System Update and Windows update doesn't do anything to update the graphics driver. Go to [Intel's support site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support.html), look for your graphics card (in my case Intel HD Graphics 620), and manually install the graphics driver. This solved the problem for me.